# RMarkdown: Long text in code chunks with multiple graphics

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, r-markdown, cat

I am preparing a R markdown document to plot some graphics and some short text accompanying each graphic. The graphics are generated in a code chunk within a loop.
Right now, it looks like this:

[image: output]

First, all the text is outputted, then the graphics. I would like this pattern:

**text**
*graphic*
**text**
*graphic*
**text**
*graphic*

Also, I don't know how to apply line breaks in the `cat()` output. This is needed to make the whole label visible.
Any ideas on these problems?

This is my code:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE, comment='', fig.width=8, fig.height=3, fig.show='hold', fig.align='center'}
        # vars is a data.frame with some variables names
        for (i in 1:nrow(vars)){
            options(warn=-1)
            label <- 'some long text'
            cat(label)
            capture.output( data <- analysisFunction(name) )
            capture.output( plottingFunctionWithGGplot2(data) )
            cat('\n\n')
          }
      ```
````

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using `cat` to explain your graphs, use seperate code blocks (`{r}\`\`\``) each one with a single plot, and explain the plots in regular text in between the code blocks.

Comment: I thought of this possibility, but it should be a dynamic document that can take care of any number of graphics and everything within one code block would be very handy. Is there no possibility to get the text / graphic / text / graphic pattern?

Comment: Add the text as a title or caption with `+ labs(title = 'x', caption = 'y')`?